# My C program's "for" loop is stalling after 3 iterations

Tags: c, for-loop, mingw

I've made a simple C program for reversing practice - however, when I enter a name and password, it iterates thrice through the `for` loop then stops and has a spinning cursor, finally exiting with no output back to the CLI. I've made changes to my algorithm and ensured it's correct (the function `x` here is not the problem, as even when returning its static value this freezing occurs). Where in my program have I gone astray? (This is my first day of C, and IDEONE said I had a buffer overflow.)

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int x(char* s, int c) {
    return 65;
}

int main(void) {

    char N[16] = ""; // Entered name
    char p[16] = ""; // Entered password
    char r[16] = ""; // Result of applying keygen `x` to `N` (`p` should be this to be correct)

    char n;
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", N);
    printf("Entered name\n");
    printf("Enter password: ");
    scanf("%s", p);
    printf("Entered password\n");

    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < strlen(N); j++) {
        printf("Iterating, iteration %d\n", j);
        if (N[j] == 0) {
            break;
        }
        n = x(N, j);
        strcat(r, &n);
    }
    if (strcmp(r, p) == 0) {
        printf("Correct!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Incorrect!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

CLI:

```
C:\MinGW\bin>gcc "\\Mac\Home\Desktop\My Crackme.c" -o "\\Mac\Home\Desktop\MyCrackme.exe"
C:\MinGW\bin>"\\Mac\Home\Desktop\MyCrackme.exe"

Enter name: Jack
Entered name
Enter password: Not Jack
Entered password
Iterating, iteration 0
Iterating, iteration 1
Iterating, iteration 2

C:\MinGW\bin>
```

This appears to only happen when I compile with MinGW into an `exe` - compiling into a generic executable with `gcc` on my Mac produces a seemingly working program. However, I need an `exe` file. All help appreciated!

Comment: Did you turn warnings of your compiler on?

Comment: `N[j] == 0` will never be true because `j<strlen(N)`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `x` is the first function, `n` is declared below the three strings. I included the check `N[j] == 0` because to my knowledge, `N` would contain the inputted chars then be filled with `0` to pad to length `16` - or is it just a suggested length?

Comment: `strlen` stops counting at the first null character.

Comment: Thanks @PaulOgilvie, useful to know! Hopefully you can answer my question :P.

Comment: I think the problem is with `strcat(r, &n);` because `*n` is not a null terminated string but a single char. `strcat` copies up until the first null it encounters, which it won't here. So your `r` will overflow, causing the abort.

Comment: I see. How best should I fix this? (Feel free to answer :D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `strcat(r, &n);` because `*n` is not a null terminated string but a single char. `strcat` copies up until the first null it encounters, which it won't here. So your `r` will overflow, causing the abort.

Instead of `strcat` you must manually append the character, for example:

```
int len= strlen(r);
*(r+len  )= n;
*(r+len+1)= '\0';
```

or (better):

```
int len= strlen(r);
if (len<sizeof(r)-1) {
    *(r+len  )= n;
    *(r+len+1)= '\0';
}
```

Comment: Looks like it works - thanks Paul! (C kinda confusing with chars/strings ngl :P)

Comment: `strcat(r, "A")` would also have worked, instead of the strange "x" function.

Comment: @Lundin `x` contains an algorithm, that `"A"` is a placeholder (as I explained in my question, replacing it does not help)